# Help with bibliography output

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Can you help get my document to compile and my references to show?
I use endnote to create my `.bib` I used to use `natbib` and im trying to switch over.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption} %subfigure
\usepackage{caption} %subfigure
\usepackage{changepage} %indentsforquotes
\usepackage{lipsum} %indents for quotes
\graphicspath{{./dissertation/}}
\usepackage{float}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % numebrs pages
\doublespacing %double spaced lines

%bib
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


%title page

\title{Sails}
\date{Submitted: August 31 2022}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage} 
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} %does not number first page

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\section{Abstract}

enter an abstract? 

\section{Introduction}

quote about sails

followed by a picture

Decoration. To the Romans, colour displayed wealth and royalty. Blue and purple were the colours that boasted of wealth, after the murex dye trade. From textual evidence available, we know that the Romans coloured their sails. \cite{RN201}.

%references list
\pagebreak

\subsection*{Ancient Sources}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Res Gestae
\end{enumerate}

\pagebreak
insert references here
\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

and here is my .bib

```
@article{RN577,
   author = {Bendig, Charles D.},
   title = {Ships’ Pumps: From Antiquity to the Early Modern Era},
   journal = {Journal of maritime archaeology},
   volume = {15},
   number = {2},
   pages = {185-207},
   ISSN = {1557-2285},
   DOI = {10.1007/s11457-020-09257-x},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@book{RN369,
   author = {Beresford, J.},
   title = {The Ancient Sailing Season},
   publisher = {Brill},
   ISBN = {9789004223523},
   url = {https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=I6hXy3gclpkC},
   year = {2012},
   type = {Book}
}

@article{RN206,
   author = {Cohen, Maayan and Cvikel, Deborah},
   title = {Rigging of the Ma'agan Mikhael B shipwreck (7th-8th centuries AD): new finds},
   journal = {The International Journal of Nautical Archaeology},
   volume = {49},
   number = {2},
   pages = {291-302},
   ISSN = {1057-2414},
   DOI = {10.1111/1095-9270.12423},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN208,
   author = {Garmi, Déjla and Meunier, Laure and Mouchard, Jimmy and Guyon, Marc},
   title = {Roman archaeological textiles discovered in nautical and port contexts: the cases of Rezé/Ratiatum (Loire-Atlantique) and Lyon/Lugdunum (Rhône)},
   journal = {Gallia},
   volume = {77},
   number = {1},
   pages = {187-211},
   ISSN = {0016-4119},
   DOI = {10.4000/gallia.5513},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@incollection{RN203,
   author = {Leidwanger, Justin},
   title = {Roman Seas},
   publisher = {New York: Oxford University Press},
   address = {New York},
   ISBN = {0190083654
9780190083656},
   DOI = {10.1093/oso/9780190083656.003.0004},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Book Section}
}

@article{RN216,
   author = {Palmer, Colin},
   title = {Windward Sailing Capabilities of Ancient Vessels},
   journal = {The International Journal of Nautical Archaeology},
   volume = {38},
   number = {2},
   pages = {314-330},
   ISSN = {1057-2414},
   DOI = {10.1111/j.1095-9270.2008.00208.x},
   year = {2009},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN205,
   author = {Pines, Miriam and Avshalom-Gorni, Dina and Shalev, Sariel and Marom, Nimrod},
   title = {Migdal of the dyers: Archaeozoological evidence for sail manufacturing in early Roman Migdal, Galilee},
   journal = {Journal Of Archaeological Science: Reports},
   volume = {33},
   ISSN = {2352-409X},
   DOI = {10.1016/j.jasrep.2020.102485},
   year = {2020},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN214,
   author = {Polzer, Mark E.},
   title = {Toggles and Sails in the Ancient World: Rigging Elements Recovered from the Tantura B Shipwreck, Israel},
   journal = {The International journal of nautical archaeology},
   volume = {37},
   number = {2},
   pages = {225-252},
   ISSN = {1057-2414},
   DOI = {10.1111/j.1095-9270.2008.00188.x},
   year = {2008},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN201,
   author = {Tilley, Alec},
   title = {Balancing Sailing Rigs},
   journal = {The International Journal of Nautical Archaeology},
   volume = {40},
   number = {2},
   pages = {432-432},
   ISSN = {1057-2414},
   DOI = {10.1111/j.1095-9270.2011.00323.x},
   year = {2011},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN207,
   author = {Whitewright, Julian},
   title = {Roman Rigging Material from the Red Sea Port of Myos Hormos},
   journal = {The International Journal of Nautical Archaeology},
   volume = {36},
   number = {2},
   pages = {282-292},
   ISSN = {1057-2414},
   DOI = {10.1111/j.1095-9270.2007.00150.x},
   year = {2007},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN209,
   author = {Whitewright, Julian},
   title = {The Potential Performance of Ancient Mediterranean Sailing Rigs},
   journal = {The International Journal of Nautical Archaeology},
   volume = {40},
   number = {1},
   pages = {2-17},
   ISSN = {1057-2414},
   DOI = {10.1111/j.1095-9270.2010.00276.x},
   year = {2011},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN212,
   author = {Whitewright, Julian},
   title = {Technological Continuity and Change: The Lateen Sail of the Medieval Mediterranean},
   journal = {Al-Masaq},
   volume = {24},
   number = {1},
   pages = {1-19},
   ISSN = {0950-3110},
   DOI = {10.1080/09503110.2012.655580},
   year = {2012},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN210,
   author = {Whitewright, Julian},
   title = {Sailing and Sailing Rigs in the Ancient Mediterranean: implications of continuity, variation and change in propulsion technology},
   journal = {The International Journal Of Nautical Archaeology},
   volume = {47},
   number = {1},
   pages = {pp28-44},
   ISSN = {1057-2414},
   DOI = {10.1111/1095-9270.12278},
   year = {2018},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{RN211,
   author = {Wild, Felicity C. and Wild, John P.},
   title = {Sails from the Roman port at Berenike, Egypt},
   journal = {The International Journal of Nautical Archaeology},
   volume = {30},
   number = {2},
   pages = {211-220},
   ISSN = {1057-2414},
   DOI = {10.1006/ijna.2001.0354},
   year = {2001},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

This is the output I get
[image: my output on my console]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. As the warnings say, you need to run `biber` on your file to process the bibliography. Also `biblatex` likes to have `babel` loaded with the appropriate language stated. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/).

Comment: There's a stray undefined `\begin{counted}` with no matching `\end{counted}` in that code as well. Remove that and compile with (pdf)(xe)(lua)latex, then biber, then latex twice more and it should work.

Comment: Sorry I will take that out, thanks @frabjous!

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks, I have never used biber before I will check out those posts!

Comment: would you recommend sticking with biblatex or working with bibtex?

Comment: With your example code I cannot reproduce the warnings about "Language 'latex' not supported", but usually that appears if you load `polyglossia` without setting a main document language (which makes little sense anyway). Your main problem is quite probably that you did not run Biber as Alan already pointed out.

Comment: @AlanMunn how do I add biber to MikTex, when I currently have it onXelatex+makeindex+bibtex

Comment: MikTeX is a TeX distribution and almost certainly comes with biber by default unless you have a very old version. I think what you need to know is how to set your editor to run it instead of bibtex. But you haven't said what editor you're using.

Comment: @Leah If you look at the second link in my comment you should be able to find out how to configure your editor to run `biber`.